# PHP export data from sql to excel

Tags: php, sql, excel

I have some problem when i try to get data from SQL and save it on excel, i want to download only the data from the login user, from the session.

This is an example of what i want to do:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM tickets_list WHERE UserName = '".$_SESSION['useruid']."'");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

The top code is not working... what is working is:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM tickets_list");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

But i don't want to get in the excel file from all the users..

Can anyone please tell me what i do wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello @Zaron, welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your `UserName` column actually have this combination of letter upper/lower case? And what error is MySQL giving you?

Comment: What does "_is not working_" mean? Blank page? Wrong results? No results? Did you start your session? Is `$_SESSION['useruid']` filled? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake in SQL,
You are searching Username by UserId. That's why it shows this.

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM tickets_list WHERE UserName 
  ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

**Please, check this.**

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have fix the problem by start the session at the top of the page.